# Enable \citet using splncs03 bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to use the `\citet{Author2016}` command as it is possible when using  `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

I **have** to use `\bibliographystyle{splncs03}` and thus cannot simply change the style of my bibliography.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=FALSE]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bibnames}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\leftline{References}}}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter         
\title{Title}
\titlerunning{Title}
\author{Blinded}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}
\citet{Hogan2009}
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\end{document}
```

Refs.bib:

```
@article{Hogan2009,
author = {Hogan, Hulk},
journal = {Int. J. of Wrestling},
number = {1},
pages = {12--50},
title = {{Wrestling III}},
volume = {1},
year = {2009}
}
```

Comment: Welcome, `citet` is only available with package `natbib`. This is your key, not the bibliographystyle.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have \usepackage{natbib} in my preamble, but still the command does not work as intended. Do you have any idea how to make citet work in this situation? Will provide a MWE in original question.

Comment: It seems as though you have two accounts, you might want to ask Stackexchange staff to merge them so you can accept answers to your question.

Comment: The `splncs03` style is not compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: @moewe: This was a copy-paste error as I removed path to file to remove clutter... Of course, the original reference contains an author field and still, the citet is not working (will fix in MWE).

Comment: OK I see, egreg is right, the style `splncs03` just does not like `natbib` and its `\citet` command. If you have to use this `.bst` style, you cant use `natbib`'s `\citet`, but no-one should expect you to, either.